# Limit the number of rows in a LENGTH statement

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following mysql code in a view

```
SELECT 
threadid,
SUM(LENGTH(pagetext)-LENGTH(REPLACE(pagetext, ' ', ''))+1)

FROM post
GROUP by threadid
```

This count the number of words in each column with the same "threadid", and return the results grouped by the threadid. It works fine, but I want to limit the words counted only for the first 5 rows in each column. How can this be achieved?

Table Structure

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| threadID        | pagetext    |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 3               | some text   |
| 3               | other text  |
| 5               | text        |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

The view returns

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| threadID        | count       |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 3               | 4           |
| 5               | 1           |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

I'm looking to limit the count number to only n rows for each threadID. For example, if I limit the count to only 1 row, the threadID "3" will have a "count" of 2.

Comment: Please show table structure (CREATE TABLE statement).

Comment: @Devart I hope this explains better

Comment: The answer is accepted. I just can say - 'Agree with rabudde about additional auto-incremented field'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    threadid,
    SUM(LENGTH(pagetext)-LENGTH(REPLACE(pagetext, ' ', ''))+1) AS len
FROM (
    SELECT
        p1.threadid,
        p2.pagetext,
        COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM post AS p1
    JOIN post AS p2 ON p1.threadid=p2.threadid AND p1.postid <= p2.postid
    GROUP BY p1.threadid, p2.pagetext
    HAVING num<=5
) a
GROUP BY threadid
```

**EDIT:** Best way could be, that there is an auto-incremented column (I'll name it `postid`), which helps us to get the first five posts for each thread.

Comment: I fail to understand your code, could you format it. (I think you are missing FROM or it has some mistakes)

Comment: there was only an alias missing for the subquery, syntax is correct now

Comment: seems like we are getting close. I get the following where I run your code

Subquery returns more than 1 row

When I remove the "x.", I get some good/bad results, not sure why.

Comment: stupid me, can you test modified version again. but there has to be an autoincremented column (named `postid` or so) in this table

Comment: This awesome, it does the job ;)

Comment: it's only an unique identifier for each row in your post table. for efficiency this should be an integer column with auto-increment functionality on it.

Comment: Okay, I have another column which is also postid. They are unique, and I want the selection to be ordered. Does it make sense?

Comment: Or is it possible to apply an ordering for the selected columns?

Comment: Basing on which column should it be sorted and in which direction? (i.e. latest comments)

Comment: There is a column (postid). It has unique integers (5, 6, 7...). Each 'pagetext' has a different 'postid'. I want it to be sorted from the smallest number. Actually, it's doing the inverse.

Comment: then change `p1.postid <= p2.postid` to `p1.postid >= p2.postid`. this should do the job

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The "postid" I'm talking about is a real column in my table. I think what we should do is to sort the table by "postid" before making the selection. makes sense?

Comment: Sure, I know that `postid` is a real column, else this statement won't work. Add an `ORDER BY p1.postid ASC` after `HAVING` clause

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is that postid is not auto-incremented. This means that a threadid with its' different pagetext have different postid(s) which are not consequent (5, 9, 34). Does this makes a difference?

Comment: If I'm not wrong the statement should order the postid for the whole table. I want them to be ordered for each "threadid".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3620/discussion-between-rabudde-and-omar-abid)